# Java Logging in Azure ApiApp

Tags: java, azure, logging

I need some help with logging for Java Apps in Azure:

1)
Using Azure as PaaS, I've created an API APP configured to use Java8 + Tomcat8.
And I'm trying to use log4j2 for getting application logging apart from the Tomcat logs (in a separated file).
For what I know, I've permissions to write anywhere inside D:\home. So, I'll try to write to "d:\home\Logfiles\Application\".
So, I created a WebApplication with some log4j2 that runs just fine in my local tomcat.
But when running the same application (with the correct log file path) in Azure I don't see any logs.
I even tried to fill /site/wwwroot/web.config as described in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/ no logs this way also.
How can I configure Java applicational logging in a separated file (without changing the tomcat logging (JULI logger) to log4j)?

2)
Looking at the tomcat logs, I realized the Start/Stop/Restart of the WebApp doesn't mean to Start/Stop/Restart of the tomcat, so we don't have any control of it?
Does someone knows what's happening behind when we do a Start/Stop/Restart in the azure portal for a webcontainer based application?

3)
 What's the best way to centralize Java Logging of several web applications? Using JDBCAppender or JPAAppender from log4j2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As I known, you have permission to write anywhere inside the path `D:\home\site\`, but not at the path `D:\home\` that I tested. So I suggest that you can try to configure the specified path inside `D:\home\site\` for application logging.

However, for logging persistence, I recommend that you can try to use Azure Table Storage for application logging. Please refer to the answered SO thread [Using Azure Blob Storage with java MVC Azure Web Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221330/using-azure-blob-storage-with-java-mvc-azure-web-site/35266057#35266057) to know.

For your second question, you can use the `Process explorer` of Kudu tool to inspect the `java` process via the url `https://<your-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer/`, please see the figure below. When you stop the app, the `java` process will be killed. If you start the app again, you can see the `java` process after you firstly access the app.

[image]

For the third question, per my experience, I think using Azure Application Insights service is the best way. Meanwhile, Azure Application Insights support Log4j2 via the [SDK](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/applicationinsights-logging-log4j2). You can refer to the offical document [`Explore Java trace logs in Application Insights`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-java-trace-logs/) to know how to get started.

Comment: Thanks Peter, the Kudu Process Explorer really helps to understand what his happening behind. :)

Answer (score 0):

**For question 1, 2 & 3:**
Using the Kudu Debug Console I saw that I don't have any java process running, that's why nothing was working. Thanks for the tip!

Setting the "Always On" = "On" in "Application settings" solved my problem.

Now, even the centralized Application Insights monitoring and logs are working just fine.

Thanks a lot :)